# Проверка формы на Ajax + занесения данных в БД

Tags: php, html, ajax, база-данных, form

Здравствуйте

1. Есть форма HTML

   ```
   <form role="form" id="formSubscribe" action="" method="post">

       <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailSubscribe" name="emailSubscribe" placeholder="Email">
           <span class="validation-error-label" id="emailSubscribeError"></span>
       </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-info" id="submitSubscribe" name="submitSubscribe">Подписаться <i class="icon-checkmark4 position-right"></i></button>

   </form>
   ```
2. php обработчик формы

   ```
   /* Массив с ошибками по умолчанию пустой */

   $errorEmailSubscribe = [];

   /* Если была нажата кнопка Подписаться */

   if (isset($form['submitSubscribe'])) {

       /* Если поле не заполнено */

       if ($form['emailSubscribe'] == '') {
           $errorEmailSubscribe[] = $text['1005'];
       }

       /* Проверка на минимальное количество символов в строке */

       if (strlen($form['emailSubscribe']) < Validator::MIN_EMAIL) {
           $errorEmailSubscribe[] = $text['1011'];
       }

       /* Проверка на максимальное количество символов в строке */

       if (strlen($form['emailSubscribe']) > Validator::MAX_EMAIL) {
           $errorEmailSubscribe[] = $text['1012'];
       }

       /* Проверка корректности поля */

       if (!preg_match(Validator::PREG_MATCH_EMAIL, $form['emailSubscribe'])) {
           $errorEmailSubscribe[] = $text['1013'];
       }

       /* Проверка на существования поля в БД */

       if (R::count(DB::MAIN.DB::TABLE_SUBSCRIBE, 'email = ?', [$form['emailSubscribe']]) > Config::HIDDEN) {
           $errorEmailSubscribe[] = $text['1043'];
       }

       trim($form['emailSubscribe']);

       /* Если ошибок нет заносим в БД */

       if (empty($errorEmailSubscribe)) {

           $dispense = R::dispense(DB::MAIN.DB::TABLE_SUBSCRIBE);
           $dispense['email'] = $form['emailSubscribe'];
           R::store($dispense);

           /* Эта сессия показывает уведомление об успешном заполнении формы */

           $_SESSION['modal'] = true;

           /* Функция перезагрузки страницы с сбросом данных с формы */

           $assistant->redirectCurrentUrl();

       }

   }
   ```
3. в переменной `$errorEmailSubscribe` храниться просто текст ошибки например (Максимальная длина email 32 символа)
4. Потом на front-end вывожу ошибки если они есть, если нет вывожу уведомление что все нормально
5. В теге span с ID `emailSubscribeError` я вывожу все ошибки по очереди с помощью функции `array_shift()`

Прошу помощи в написании JS скрипта который бы проверял все ошибки на Ajax без перезагрузки страницы.

Перелопатил весь google много информации нашел, но все без успешно, так как все показывают примеры проверки ajax без занесения данных в БД.

Comment: С занесением данных в БД так же, как без занесения, только ещё на php добавить код для занесения. Он, кстати, у вас уже есть. В скрипте добавьте ответ в виде json, в котором будет содержаться статус, успешно добавлено, или нет, и если нет, будут возвращаться ошибки

Comment: В коде который я предоставил уже все реализовано, проблема заключается исключительно в ajax

Comment: Какая проблема? Не вижу у вас в примере ajax

Comment: в это то и дело, что все готово кроме ajax

Comment: Здесь не пишут код бесплатно, здесь помогают, когда что-то не получается. Напишите ajax, и когда что-то конкретно не будет работать, спрашивайте

Comment: к сожалению все мои попытки в написания скрипта ajax без успешны, и выкладывать то что я пытался написать, нет никакого смысла ведь я даже ничего не понимаю что я делал и как, а просто копипастил и пытался что то сделать методом тыка

Answer (score 0):

ajax отправляется как-то так:

```js
$('#formSubscribe').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/script.php',
    data: {email: $('#emailSubscribe').val()},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
      console.log(request);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="formSubscribe" action="" method="post">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailSubscribe" name="emailSubscribe" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="validation-error-label" id="emailSubscribeError"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-info" id="submitSubscribe" name="submitSubscribe">Подписаться <i class="icon-checkmark4 position-right"></i></button>

</form>
```

Comment: если у меня обработчик формы уже подключен и на этой же странице, что мне написать вместо url: '/script.php',?

Comment: php обработчик перестал работать из за e.preventDefault();

Comment: В каком смысле "обработчик перестал работать"?

Comment: я полагаю из за отмены действия по кнопке

Comment: Ну так правильно, не надо самбитить форму, если мы делаем ajax